# ASP.NET - Control dropdownlist postback programmatically

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have two dropdownlists on my form-ddl1 and ddl2. They  together determine the visibility of a textbox -txt1. For that I do this check:

```
if (ddl1.SelectedIndex==2 && ddl2.SelectedIndex>2)
   {
     if (!txt1.Visible)
        {txt1.Visible=true;// And then I want to call postback}

   }
else
   {
     if (txt1.Visible)
        {txt1.Visible=false;// And then I want to call postback}
   }
```

As you can see, I want to post the page to server only if the above condions are true. The code above is triggered on SelectedIndexChanged event of the both dropdownlists. How can I or is it possible to achieve upon a condition?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do - the form has already been posted back after the index was changed - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've set the AutoPostBack to false. So when I change the index it does not postback.

Comment: Right OK, so you don't want to Postback each time the index changes - only when the conditions above are met? is that correct?

Comment: That's right. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand your problem but you want to achieve postback only if certain condition is met. you can hook up a javascript function on both dropdown **onchange="return onchange();"** Set Autopostback = true;

```
      function Onchange() {
        var ddl1 = document.getElementById('<%= ddl1.ClientID %>');
        var ddl2 = document.getElementById('<%= ddl2.ClientID %>');
        var txtbox = document.getElementById('<%= txtbox.ClientID %>');
        if (ddl1.selectedIndex == 2 && ddl2.selectedIndex > 2) {
            txtbox.style.display = "inline";
            __doPostBack(ddl1, '');
        }
        else {
            txtbox.style.display = "none";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Aspx code should look like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddl1" onchange="return Onchange();"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text3" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text4" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddl2" onchange="return Onchange();"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text3" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="text4" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox" />
```

Tested it and it works...

Comment: Thanks Kamran. That's fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If AutoPostBack = True, which  it would have to be for your events to be firing just call a funciton when your condition is met.  ASP.NET is always posting back, you just need to handle the condition, otherwise you have to handle the validation with JavaScript and manually post the page:

```
   if (ddl1.SelectedIndex==2 && ddl2.SelectedIndex>2)
   {
        if (!txt1.Visible)
        {
           txt1.Visible=true;// And then I want to call postback
           //dowork
        }

   }
   else
   {
        if (txt1.Visible)
        {
            txt1.Visible=false;// And then I want to call postback
            //do work
        }
   }
```

Comment: Now I realize that SelectedIndexChanged event is a server side event. So the postback is required. I probably need JavaScript to do this but do not know how.